# Exporting project on QGIS so that it opens as it is on another system?

Tags: qgis

I have aligned different screenshots of India on a OSM basemap on QGIS, using the [Freehand Raster Georeferencer](https://github.com/gvellut/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer) plugin.

I want to send this exact file with the same extent and alignment of images to someone. I sent the .qgz file but when I open it on another system it shows "freehand  raster georeferencer: Image not found".

How can I export this file so that it also works on another system and all the images remain at the same position?

This the folder with all the screenshots as well as the .qgz file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eB2MV6JFXI-bInosyLrSEgIou3yictHA?usp=sharing

[image: This is the how it looks.]

Comment: QGIS project files only store links to layers, not the layers/features/images themselves. You need to provide everything to the receiver. Be sure to save the project with relative file paths. Another option would be to put everything into a geopackage.

Comment: I tried putting it in the geopackage but that doesn't work, how do you add the jpg images as a layer in the geopackage. I have sent the same folder that is shared here with the receiver, and they got the error  "freehand raster georeferencer: Image not found".

Comment: There is a plugin called QPackage.  It will copy your project and all contents to a folder which you can give to another person.  In my experience that works well, but for some reason the project's paths are not updated to the new folder.  This can be fixed relatively easy, however.  Open the project and tell it to keep all layers.  Click on a layer with the icon for missing data and browse to the layer in the package folder.  This fixes that layer but it may lead to all being fixed.  If it doesn't use the changeDataSource plugin which has nice options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have georeferenced the raster, it is still only a temporary layer. You must export each georeferenced raster in your project with a world file.

Select them one at a time in the layers panel and click this button:

[image]

Choose a save location:

[image]

Repeat this for every georeferenced raster in your project.

Find your exported images and drag these into your project as new layers.

[image]

Then you should be able to send the project as you did before.

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the solution. I saw this export tool but I didn't know what export with world file meant. Thanks again!